# Indy 10 TIdHTTP in Lazarus is losing Unicode characters

Tags: unicode, utf-8, indy, lazarus, indy10

I am currently using Lazarus 1.6.4 for a mobile app, and I am making an Indy `TIdHTTP.Get()` call to a web server, which returns a JSON string in UTF-8 format.

The string contains Unicode characters that I cannot see in Lazarus, where the response is converted with multiple `?` characters (one for each Unicode character).

For example, I want to get `["id","code","name"],[2,"100","ΤΕΣΤ"]`, but I receive `["id","code","name"],[2,"100","????"]`.

I have an older version of Lazarus, and I don't have any problems with the encoding.  I also perform the call from other applications/browsers with no problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: The question marks mean the data is passing through a charset conversion that does not support the characters being converted. How exactly are you converting the raw data to a string? Are you letting `TIdHTTP` do the conversion for you, or are you converting it yourself after the download? If the former, is the webserver correctly reporting the JSON is being sent as UTF-8? If the latter, are you performing an actual UTF-8 conversion? And what version of Indy 10 are you using exactly? Please show a [mcve] demonstrating the code you are having trouble with.

Comment: Hey Remy thanks for replying.

i have the following code

var http:TidHttp;
      str:string;

http:=TIdHTTP.create(nil);
str:=http.Get('http://webserviceurl') ;  

the web service performs correctly the conversion to urf8 so i i do not perform any conversion within the tidhttp. (indy version used 10_5438)

i also tried the following from the lazarus documentation but nothing

"To disable the new UTF-8 mode, -dDisableUTF8RTL must be defined in project options"

Comment: So, again, does the web server report the data is UTF-8? What is the actual value of the server's `Content-Type` header? Does it have a `charset` attribute that says UTF-8? If not, that can cause the problem. The alternative is to download the raw data to a `TMemoryStream` instead of a `String`, and then use Indy's `ReadStringFromStream()` function passing `IndyTextEncoding_UTF8` in the `AByteEncoding` parameter.

Comment: yes the web server reports the data as UTF-8. i have already tried with memory stream and it works fine but i wanted to avoid making changes through out the whole project that is already working with a previous version of lazarus....thanks again remy if i find a solution for the string i will post it here.for now i will continue with the alternative of the memory stream :)